# Kotlin generic for Void and value

Tags: generics, kotlin

In Kotlin, is there a way to pass a generic type that will also works with `Void` type?

I want to pass a `Task<*>` which can have either `Void` or a valid `Credential` object type.

How I can modify the constructor
`class TaskWrapperImpl(private val task: Task<Any>) {}`

Here is how I am using this class:

`val taskWrapper = TaskWrapperImpl(googleSignInClient.signOut())`

`googleSignInClient.signOut()` returns `Task<Void!>!`

Comment: `Any?` should work?

Comment: It does not work, compiler says: Required `Task<Any?>`, found `Task<Void!>!`

Comment: What's wrong with `Task<*>`, which you mention in the question? If you want "only `Void` or a subtype of `Credential`", that's impossible (though you could make the primary constructor private and add secondary constructors with desired type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, the following code is what I was looking for:

`class TaskWrapperImpl <T> constructor(task: Task<T>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Unit` this way:

```
class TaskWrapperImpl(private val task: Task<Unit>) {}
```

Comment: It does not work. Compiler says. Required `Task<Unit>`, found `Task<Void!>!`